# PrimeFaces features not recognized

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces, wildfly

I want to build a minimum working example of a JEE PrimeFaces data table application showing customer information using Maven, PrimeFaces, JEE, JPA and Wildfly 8.2.
The application works, but without any front-end PrimeFaces features (no styles, etc.)[image: prime faces customers page]

Could you help me find out what the problem is?

Here are my files:

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>javakurs3.bibliothek-jsf.datatable</groupId>
  <artifactId>javakurs3.bibliothek-jsf.datatable.customers</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>javakurs3.bibliothek-jsf.datatable.customers Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-web</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>javakurs3.bibliothek-jsf.datatable</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is my project structure in Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: What does a view-source in the client show? Go further hrom there

Comment: Or the developer console logging of network traffic

Comment: maybe just a missing h:head.

Comment: @tandraschko thank you, that solved my problem! It was actually a missing h:head!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tandraschko suggested, the problem was in the missing h:head tag in the beginning of the jsf page.
Now it works!